# 10th Anniversary of Amateur Radio SE!

Tags: discussion

In October [ham.stackexchange.com](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) turned 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!

Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.

How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

Answer (score 3):

Being a long-time StackOverflow user, I wandered into this stack a few years ago just by chance.  I've been amazed at the wealth of experience and knowledge in this group.  Some of that knowledge is hard-won from hands on experience and some of it is from what seems to be a career in radio or electronics engineering.

Good to be with you all.

Comment: Congratulations on 10 years of Amateur Radio, David. Thank you, Kevin Reid AG6YO, and Scott Earle for all you do as moderators. Congratulations to everyone in the community.